# intercept click only on "clickable" elements using jquery (or javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, click

Good day all.
I've got this problem today: let's assume that I have hundreds of pages, with "almost" the same structure (but it is not mandatory). this pages are already done, and I can only view them (cannot edit html them in any way).
Also, in all (well, most) of them, jquery is included, but is included the 1.5 at this moment.

what I would like to do, is to track (via an ajax call) all the clicks on the page, before they actually do "something".

I have an injection point, at the begginning of the page, right after the inclusion of jquery (just to know it)

actually, I've bind a click event to document, right this:

```
$(document).bind('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    alert(evt.target.id+" and "+evt.target.class+" and "+evt.target.name);
    //ajax call will be here
    try{
    evt.trigger('click');
    }catch(e){}
});
```

the result is pretty forward... any click on the page fires an alert, in some cases i got an ID, some other times i got a class... or undefined end so on. The problem with this solution is that every single click is binded, and this is really a blind way, I would like to get only clicks from those "clickable" elements such as links, buttons, checkboxes... while ignoring divs, html elements... body, and so on.

**Is there a trick where I can select only those elements that permit a click on them**? or it is not possible? and the second question is... is that `preventDefault` handled in a good way by adding at the end the `evt.trigger('click')`? I mean, I can't broke all those page, just becouse i put a preventdefault at the beginning, I must preserve the functionality of those elements...

I'm not searching for a out of the box solution, I just want to understand if it's possible... or if there is some hack, cheat, well...something i could use to achieve this.

any ideas?

My second solution is to write down all classes,ids,names of those clicckable elements of every single page... but they are hundreds... and this is a bit... well... you got it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I was going to suggest using $(document).on("click","[your selector]",function(){}) but I noticed your version limitation :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is a jQuery selector like `$('input[type=button],input[type=submit],input[type=reset], button, a').bind(...` out of the question?

Comment: no, it should not, it could be a way. it is surely more efficent than everithing bind :)
i didn't think about input[type=....] nice shot.

Comment: thinking about it... is this work also for an <a><span>click me</span></a> element? will the click be from the "a" or the "span" in this case?